# finite looping in xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

```
<data id="5">
</data>



<xsl:template match="data">
 <div class="holder">
  <!-- Print this as many time as id attribute have -->
  <b>Print this 5 times</b>
  <!-- block end -->
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to print some html code fragment 5 times using xslt. how to do it?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to loop in XSLT?

Comment: @ArthurChamz I can't think of any other way to solve it. I am happy to hear any other idea or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a recursive template that runs until it matches the **id** in your element.

Here is what that could look like:

```
<xsl:template name="printLines">
    <xsl:param name="num" />
    <xsl:param name="id" />
    <xsl:if test="not($num = $id)">
        <b>Print this line</b>
        <xsl:call-template name="printLines">
            <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And you can call it in your current template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
  <div class="holder">
    <xsl:call-template name="printLines">
        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="number('0')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```